# Request error after upgrading PHP from 5.6 to 7.3

Tags: php

I have a script that makes a request to an API, then returns back the response to AJAX. After updating my server from PHP 5.6 to PHP 7.3 the request is not succeding and just returns "null". This is the error I am getting:

> PHP Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.ekata.com/3.3/identity_check?'.primary.address.city=Los Angeles&primary.address.postal_code=90001&primary.address.state_code=CA&primary.address.street_line_1=7519+Wadsworth+Ave&primary.name=SteveTest+SmithTest&primary.phone=9165551234.'&api_key=XXXXXXXXXX): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!

Here is the PHP:

```
<?php

# An HTTP GET request example
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$url = $_POST['url']; 

$json = file_get_contents('https://api.ekata.com/3.3/identity_check?'.$url.'&api_key=XXXXXXX');

$obj = json_decode($json);
echo json_encode($obj, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: What's the response?

Comment: What does `console.log(data);` show in your browser console?

Comment: @treyBake But the JS error may be happening because the PHP response is empty.

Comment: @treyBake it could affect the the JS because the response might have become "invalid" because of the PHP update

Comment: Although if PHP is returning invalid JSON, you shouldn't go into the `success:` function.

Comment: Use the Network tab of the browser to see what the exact JSON response is.

Comment: @Barmar Are you sure? IIRC it wouldn't throw an error to break the request it'd just be in `json_last_error`.

Comment: You also might want to check your PHP error log.

Comment: @Script47 I was thinking of `json_encode()` sending invalid JSON. But if the problem is happening in `json_decode()`, it will return `json_encode(null)`, which is valid.

Comment: Okay when I put in console.log(data) the form seems to work, but I am getting an error  "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ." for the "console.log(data);" line. When I take out console.log(data) the form is broken again.

Comment: You already have `console.log(data)` in the code, we just wanted to know what it's showing.

Comment: What do you see in the response section of the Network tab?

Comment: Seems like your response does not contain a `primary_phone_checks` property.

Comment: console.log(data) returns null

Comment: Response section in the Network tab says "null"

Comment: I checked the PHP logs and I am getting this error:

    PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://api.ekata.com/3.3/identity_check?'.primary.address.city=Los Angeles&amp;primary.address.postal_code=90001&amp;primary.address.state_code=CA&amp;primary.address.street_line_1=7519+Wadsworth+Ave&amp;primary.name=SteveTest+SmithTest&amp;primary.phone=9165551234.'&amp;api_key=XXXXXXXXXX): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!

Comment: So your PHP warning has the single quote and the dot in it? That does not make sense. Are you sure your PHP doesn't look like `file_get_contents("'https://api.ekata.com/3.3/identity_check?'.$url.'&api_key=XXXXXXX'");` (wrapped in double quotes?)

Comment: @miken32 that didn't work

Comment: I was suggesting a mistake to check for, not something to try. The error message suggests you’re including php operators in the URL which would have nothing to do with spaces in the data.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message clearly indicates that the file_get_contents attempt to fetch a remote url is failing. You should probably be using [CURL](https://www.php.net/curl) instead. Alternatively, look at the output of phpinfo() and look for [allow_url_fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen). If this is **0** or **false** then you can try changing your php.ini settings to allow PHP to access remote urls with functions like file_get_contents.

Note that if you change php.ini, you might need to restart apache if PHP runs as a module or restart PHP-FPM is your machine is running that.

**EDIT:** I would add that your PHP script should be checking the result of the file_get_contents call before just coughing it up. If the result is empty, you should probably have your PHP script cough up some kind of error object and have your javascript check for an error condition before trying to operate on the JSON results.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was that the city field had a space in it so the API URL was invalid. Wasn't obvious until I started really looking in the Network/Response tab

```
https://proapi.whitepages.com/3.3/lead_verify?primary.address.city=Los Angeles&primary.address.postal_code=90001
```

I added this to my php file and it sent successfully:

```
$url = str_replace(" ", "%20", $url);
```

I do however need to look into CURL, so I will be doing that on our DEV site. Thank you everyone for helping me troubleshoot this.

Comment: No, don’t do this. Use `rawurlencode()` to properly encode your values.